# Arrays and Sum Iffs

Tags: arrays, excel

I did ask this question before but its parameters have expanded and I'm none-the-wiser.

So. I wish to create an array-based calculation as I am trying to learn better excel.

In this instance, I have the following columns (excuse me - I couldn't seem to make a table)

```
London      PPM     40      100
Geneva      BC      10      100
Germany     PPM     20      100
America     BC      40      100
New Zealand PPM     60      100
China       BC      80      100
London      PPM     40      100
```

The outcome of the formula is complicated. 
It needs to see where column 1 says London and where column 2 says PPM, for those rows it needs to check the value of column 3 and, taking into account there is a string in there (that pretty much equates to 100) determine whether column 3 is greater than or equal to 40 and less than 80 and multiply column 4 by those figures

It then needs to sum the entire lot.

I apologise - I have asked something very similar before in the thought that I'd figure it out but it's not worked out that way for me. So far, I have a very convoluted IF statement.

Comment: Replaced `Signed` in your range and this becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Edited - sorry I was so fixated on proving that column could only be a set of values between 5,10,20,40,60,80,Signed that I forgot to actually make the calculation do something.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the two new test to the Boolean strings:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$7="London")*($B$1:$B$7="PPM")*($C$1:$C$7>=40)*($C$1:$C$7<80),$C$1:$C$7,$D$1:$D$7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one suggestion

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10="London")*(B2:B10="PPM")*(C2:C10>=40)*(C2:C10<80),C2:C10,D2:D10)
```

Since this is the same as @Scott's, here is a slightly tricky alternative:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10="London")*(B2:B10="PPM")*(C2:C10>=40)*(C2:C10<80)*N(+C2:C10)*D2:D10)
```

:-)

[image]

Comment: Honours even I think :-)